# Windows 7 mapped drive - red X (one user out of 4)

Tags: windows-7, local-area-network, mappeddrive

This is for a client of mine.  Small Windows 2008 domain.  Four workstations, all Windows 7 Pro, all the same service pack and windows updates.  Same AV software, no GPOs, all computers are pretty identical.  All computers on a gigabit network as well.  Up until a month ago, everything was working great for all users (at least for the past year when I rebuilt the network after they moved into a new office).

All users have a login script (bat file) that maps out 2 drives from the server for them.  Very simple setup.  One user (out of the 3 others) constantly gets the red X on her drives.  Double clicking them - you'd think would restore the connection, doesn't.  She has to restart her computer (now it's a daily restart in the morning).

I followed this KB from Microsoft:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/297684
It appeared to help, but ultimately didn't.  For the life of me, I can't figure this out - and why it only happens to one user and not everyone.  Every computer is pretty much setup the same.  They all use the same software.  They all have the same network settings.

This one user, aside from that KB article.  I've replaced her NIC card, gone back and forth on giving her a static vs. DHCP IP address, disabled IPv6 since we don't use that, reset her winsock a dozen times, flushed DNS a dozen times, performed almost every network command you can imagine at a command prompt, replaced her network cable 3x's, yet the problem still persists.  Hardware, software, and logic have all been inspected inside and out.  Still a mystery.  My last step is to just wipe Windows 7 and start from scratch - but that seems pretty extreme to resolve this.

Any suggestions or ideas about this?  Thank you in advance for your reply.

Comment: I had this once before and `net config server /autodisconnect:-1` didn't work but `net config server /autodisconnect:65535` did. Also try `netsh interface tcp set global autotuning=disabled`

Comment: I did the net config server /autodisconnect:-1 on the workstation and server.  Didn't help.  I will try the 65535 though on the workstation and server tonight.  I'll try the netsh as well and see how that works.  Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

When I came across this, it was because the user had also taken the liberty of doing a manual mapped drive along with the bat that maps their drives, so the drives/letters overlapped each other. The user above that wrote the net config server command has the command to undo that, but this is generally why.

Log the user on with a different profile on the same PC and see if it does it again. If it doesn't, and that command doesn't work, might be worth while to scratch her profile and redo it.